How to run a background task from within a route's handler in Ktor
How to run a long-running task from a route's handler and restrict the lifetime of the task to the lifetime of the server or the entire application? How to prevent a cancellation of the task caused by exceptional behavior of the sibling tasks?

The easiest way to run a background task bound to the server lifetime is to use the Application instance, which implements the CoroutineScope to launch a coroutine:
routing {
    get {
        application.launch { // Runs until the server is stopped or the job is completed
            var i = 0
            while (i < 500) {
                println("$i Running background task...")
                delay(500)
                i++
            }
        }

        launch {
            throw RuntimeException("Yaack")
        }

        call.respondText { "OK" }
    }
}

The exception thrown from another coroutine launched from the same route's handler won't affect the execution of the background task.
A coroutine scope can be created to bind the background task's lifetime to the application lifetime. The scope can be canceled any time before the application shutdown.
val backgroundScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)

embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080) {
    routing {
        get {
            backgroundScope.launch { // Runs until the scope is canceled or the job is completed
                var i = 0
                while (i < 500) {
                    println("$i Running background task...")
                    delay(500)
                    i++
                }
            }

            call.respondText { "OK" }
        }
    }
}

